# cambiar la transiciones al cambiar de vista ionic - angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

buenas comunidad, alguien sabe si se puede ¿cambiar el estilo o tipo ed transacion al pasar cada vista? osea los elementos `ion-view`, y si se puede que en `android` muestre la animación normal y en `ios` muestre otra animación diferente, muchas gracias.

Comment: Para cambiar la transcision de cada vista `$ionicConfigProvider.views.transition(transition)` en esta url http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/provider/$ionicConfigProvider/#views.transition se muestra como seria y con http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/ detectas que plataforma

Answer (score 1):

NOTA: Por favor, edita tu pregunta para explicar la parte de "Cambiar la animación al momento de cambiar de vista" que no se entiende correctamente, luego editare la respuesta. La otra parte de la pregunta la respondo aquí:

Primero, crea las diferentes animaciones CSS de acuerdo a la plataforma:

```
.android .animacion {
   /* aqui los terminos de la animacion para android */
}

.ios .animacion {
   /* aqui los terminos de la animacion para ios */
}
```

Luego, usando un controller estableces en el `<body>` (es un ejemplo, pero sirve cualquier elemento de que este arriba en el DOM) el valor de clase que corresponde de acuerdo a la plataforma.

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic'])
.controller('bodyCtrl', function($scope) {

  ionic.Platform.ready(function(){
    $scope.isAndroid = ionic.Platform.isAndroid();
    $scope.isIOS     = ionic.Platform.isIOS();
  });

});
```

Siendo el html:

```
<body ng-controller="bodyCtrl" ng-class="{android: isAndroid, ios: isIOS }">
  ... <div class="animacion">Este es el elemento animado</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Se está debatiendo en Meta sobre las variantes de etiquetas de Ionic. ¿Te importaría darle una ojeada al debate como usuario importante en esa etiqueta? [Debate etiquetas Ionic](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4073/83)